# SQLite How to Group results by hours?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, group-by

I have following SQL command which returns count of some values.

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS DIALS_CNT,  
SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'APPT_CNT',  SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CONV_NO_APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'CONVERS_CNT' ,  
SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CANNOT_REACH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'CANNOT_REACH_CNT'  FROM dialed_calls dc ;
```

I would like to get results grouped by hours to get result like this

```
--------------------------------------------------
HOUR | APPT_CNT | CONV_NO_APPT | CANNOT_REACH_CNT
--------------------------------------------------
8:00 | 10       | 20           | 30
--------------------------------------------------
9:00 | 20       | 10           | 10
--------------------------------------------------
```

Etc..to get values for hours where are values higher than zero.

Structure of the table is below:
[image]

I suppose that simple usage of the group and having will not be good
solution.?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: pl provide all the columns and table data

Comment: I just updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime()` to extract the hour and use `group by`:

```
SELECT strftime(datetimecolumn, '%H') as hr,
       COUNT(*) AS DIALS_CNT,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS APPT_CNT,      
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CONV_NO_APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CONVERS_CNT,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CANNOT_REACH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CANNOT_REACH_CNT
FROM dialed_calls dc
GROUP BY strftime(datetimecolumn, '%H');
```

A word of advice:  don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Thanks but it returns only one row with hr<null>. Could be problem in the format of the date column, it means like : 2015-01-28 19:27:05CET ?

Comment: This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research i found that problem was in format of the datetime value (CET value for timezone is not compatible with sqlite). So if i removed CET value from datetime string i got correct result.

```
SELECT strftime('%H', dc.date) as hr,
       COUNT(*) AS DIALS_CNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS APPT_CNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CONV_NO_APPT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CONVERS_CNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = 'CANNOT_REACH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CANNOT_REACH_CNT
FROM dialed_calls dc
GROUP BY strftime('%H', dc.date);
```